# Achievements dropdown links are pointing to the wrong site

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, top-bar, achievements-dialog

When I'm on the meta site and view my achievements drop down at the head of the page:

[image: screenshot of dropdown]

The links contain relative URLs.

```
<a href="/questions/..."> ... </a>
```

This causes them all to point to Meta Stack Overflow (since this is the only place the new top-bar is implemented). Even achievements on other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It appears to construct the links like `http://currentsite/link-to-the-question-or-answer`, so cross-domain links break and it takes you to the question/answer with the same ID on the current site (MSO in this case)

Comment: Few of the links lead to *Page Not Found* and few take me to random pages which I've never even seen. This bug needs to be fixed ASAP.

Comment: That behavior is new. This morning I used it, and it worked.

Comment: @R.J - "Page Not Found" will come when *post Id* doesn't exist on MSO or redirect to the MSO post with that post Id.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that's Oscillation for you. ;)

Comment: Worth to mention that the inbox links are OK.

Comment: Can't reproduce this.

Comment: Just kidding - fixed ;)

Comment: This bug occurs again: [Positive reputation notification for edit approvals uses relative URL, which causes the link to go to the wrong place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391952/positive-reputation-notification-for-edit-approvals-uses-relative-url-which-cau)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some code moved around, when the achievements dropdown was reworked, and the linking to the correct site was mistakenly dropped.

Fixed and built out.

Comment: 22 minutes, looks like a record!

Comment: If only chat bugs would get fixed that quickly.

Comment: [Another one for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209151/152859) - bon appetit! ;)