# Badge notification in Achievements drop down links only to relevant post

Tags: feature-request, badges, achievements-dialog

When I get such item in the inbox:

> You've earned the "X" badge for "Y". See your profile.

The "See your profile" used to be a link to the profile badges tab while only the "Y" was link to the relevant post.

Now the whole item is one big link to "Y":

> [image]

Can this be changed please?

Comment: That's a bug. It used link to the badges tab. Probably related to [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209136/152859).

Comment: It links to the badges tab for tag badges, but the question for question-related badges. It is rather confused and muddled at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

We are trying very hard to get all of the inbox and notifications down to one link so we can make the entire item clickable.

This is the only element that departs from that, so we think the best option is to link to the badge page on non-question related badges and the question on question related badges.

We do have plans to make the notification more informative, including the one line badge description, but it needs a re-factor first.

I'm open to arguments that it should always go to the same place or something else...

Comment: I often wonder what the criteria for the badge is. I can tell what question/answer it was without clicking, since I am given the title, so if I could have only one link, the best would be the page you reach from your profile that shows that badge and has links to what you earned it for. Eg http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer?userid=46 for a recent badge I was notified about. From there you can see the criteria and it's just one click to the question or answer I earned it for.

Comment: I agree with @Kate here.

Comment: @KateGregory very good idea... will probably use it when we refactor the backend soon.

Comment: I also agree with @Kate. It would be nice to have the link go to the personalized badge page.

Comment: I think Kate's suggestion is great. On the topic of the wording of the notification, perhaps it could change to something resembling the badge description? For example, using Kate's badge: *"Congratulations! You've earned* **[• Great Answer]** *by having an answer score of 100 on Flight tickets: buy two weeks before even during holiday seasons?"*

Comment: As an update, I got Reviewer today and it linked to http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history which was super unhelpful. Would have preferred http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer?userid=203458