# New topbar notification for badge earning should link to badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, notifications, top-bar

In the new topbar's Achievements dropdown (the graph icon), badges that you earn are listed.  However, when you click the badge notification, it doesn't take you to the badge you earned.  For example:

[image: Achievement menu]

Here are 2 recent Achievements for me.  The top is a badge, the bottom is earned reputation from an upvote.  Both links go to the post.  The badge earning notification says 'See your profile', but nothing in that notification *links* to my profile.

In the old topbar, there was a section for recently-earned badges.  When you clicked the badges there, it would take you to a page that showed you the badge, its description, and a link to the post that earned you the badge.  Can we get that behavior back?

It's more useful to understand what the badge is and how you earned it.  The link to the post doesn't tell you anything about what's special about that post that makes it badge-worthy.

Comment: @3ventic - Related, but not dupe imo. That one requests that the link go to the profile, this one requests that it go to the badge page.

Comment: @TravisJ this comment https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209151/badge-notification-in-achievements-drop-down-links-only-to-relevant-post#comment671143_209642 suggests the badge page and is followed by a comment saying they'll probably do that

Comment: @Kate - I see, then this probably is a dupe.

Comment: it is status by design, you only redirected to your recently-earned badges page, for e.g " when 
You've earned the "Convention" badge. See your profile. "

Comment: @Bala That design is inconsistent.  Why would some badge notifications take you to the badge information page, while others would not?  They should all link to the same thing, so we know what to expect when clicking on the badge notification link.  On top of this, the 'see your profile' is an obvious bug since it doesn't link to your profile.

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice if it were something along the lines of a slight breakdown in the link.

"You've earned the "Necromancer" badge for Who was the first Avatar?." should still link to the post.

However, the suffix should change from "See your profile" to "View your badge" where the badge would link to the badge page. In this specific case, it would be like this:

[You've earned the "Necromancer" badge for Who was the first Avatar?.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/who-was-the-first-avatar/38338#38338) [View your badge.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/good-answer?userid=1027)