# The OP styling has disappeared from the suggested edit history

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits

When a suggested edit was reviewed by the OP of a post, the "OP styling" - that background that shows up on the OP's username for comments and other actions associated with the post - used to be applied as well. It clarifies that it was OP who took the action, as, except for mods, they're the only person to have unilateral approve / reject privileges. However, that recently seems to have disappeared, showing the OP like any other reviewer:

[image: "approved" banner. It shows one reviewer as approving, with no special formatting.]

This is potentially confusing and is inconsistent with other styling around the OP taking actions surrounding their post. Can this please be added back? (Although there are [more urgent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391952/294691) bugs with suggested edits that should be fixed first...)

Comment: It was broken on purpose (aka "design change") hence not really a bug.